# documented android app memory limitation

Tags: android, memory, document, limit

I have came across some blogs describing the memory limitation imposed by android system on a running app, but I couldn't find the official document of such topic, can anyone points me to the place where it is mentioned in android official document? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation you may want is probably the [activity manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html) official documentation. Take a look at the listed methods there, such as

`getLargeMemoryClass(), getMemoryClass(), getMemoryInfo(ActivityManager.MemoryInfo outInfo),` etc

hope that helps.